# Custom Attribute null reference exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an view model

```
public class fooViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [CustomAttribute]
    public float foo1{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    [CustomAttribute]
    public decimal foo2 { get; set; }
}
```

I made a custom server side validation attribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class CustomAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public CustomAttribute()
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Some message";
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        string input = value.ToString();
        //some validation logic
        return result;
    }
}
```

The problem is that my value parameter sometimes is null, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: `CustomAttribute` is used on  `decimal` and `float`. They can not be null.

Comment: @EmrahSüngü foo1 and foo2 are not null but value is...

Comment: Do you use `CustomAttribute` at any other place?

Comment: @EmrahSüngü no only in this view model at foo1 and foo2

Comment: @EmrahSüngü oh now i think i see what the problem is ... when I use a wrong culture number it's null ... any idea how to fix it?